# Some algebraic shortcut to solve this problem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, optimization, roots

When solving this problem I arrive to a cubic equation not very friendly, is there any algebraic shortcut?

$$W=\frac{3+\left [ \sqrt[3]{4+\sqrt[3]{4+...}} \right ]^{2}}{1+\left [ \sqrt[3]{4+\sqrt[3]{4+...}} \right ]^{-1}}$$

to do this
$$P= \sqrt[3]{4+\sqrt[3]{4+...}}$$
$$P^{3}= 4+\sqrt[3]{4+...}$$
$$P^{3}=4+P$$
$$P^{3}-P-4=0$$
$$P≈1,7963$$

evaluating the expression I arrive at approximately 4, but the cubic I solved it by software.
Is there another way to approach this problem?

Comment: If you seek just $P$, you can use Cardano's formula. For the depressed cubic $x^3 + px + q = 0$, we have a real root (provided $4p^3 + 27q^2 > 0$)

$$\xi = \sqrt[3]{-\frac q2+\sqrt{\frac{q^2}4+\frac{p^3}{27}}} +\sqrt[3]{-\frac q2-\sqrt{\frac{q^2}4+\frac{p^3}{27}}}$$

Here $p=-1$ and $q=-4$. The necessary condition is trivially satisfied. Plugging in these values yields

$$\xi = \frac{ \sqrt[3]{18 - \sqrt{321}} + \sqrt[3]{18 + \sqrt{321}}}{\sqrt[3]{9}}$$

per [Wolfram](https://v.gd/q75mzd).

Comment: @Eevee Trainer,thanks but that's what I want to avoid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the nested cube-root converges, which I believe it does, let $x$ be the unique real root of $P^3-P-4$. Then $x^3 = x+4$, and therefore
$$
W=\frac{3+x^2}{1+x^{-1}}= \frac{3x+x^3}{x+1} = \frac{3x+x+4}{x+1}
= \frac{4x+4}{x+1} = 4.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$W=\frac{3+P^2}{1+\frac{1}{P}}$$

multiply top and bottom by $P$,

$$W=\frac{3P+P^3}{1+P}=\frac{4P+4}{1+P}=4$$

Comment: Why the downvote ?